# Why do some wildcard searches produce different results when track changes is on?

Tags: search, microsoft-word-2013

In Microsoft Word 2013, I'm trying to set up an automated wildcard search, but the results I'm getting are different depending on whether track changes is on or off.
In this example, I need to change the construction 1Q 2010 to 1Q10.
I've written the following wildcard:

```
([1-4])Q [0-9][0-9]([0-9][0-9])
```

I'm replacing it with:

```
\1Q\2
```

When I run the search with track changes *off*, I get the correct result: 1Q10. When I run it with track changes *on*, I get 110Q instead. All the right elements, but in the wrong order.

If I slightly modify the search expression to:

```
([1-4])([Q]) [0-9][0-9]([0-9][0-9])
```

and the replace expression to:

```
\1\2\3
```

I get the correct output regardless of whether track changes is on or off. I would just use this syntax, but it doesn't make sense to me that "Q" needs to be treated as a wildcard, and if someone else ever has to modify/update my searching tool, they'll run into similar problems when they try to create new entries. It's non-intuitive that a constant in this expression should have to be treated as a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known, but *old* issue.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/wildcard-find-and-replace-with-track-changes/cd35b715-f539-4d0b-902d-7f977dcf67e5

The workaround is to simply make each element of the search (even the constants) a wildcard.